# Access 2010 query return 4 options based on two criteria

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a scenario where I have two table columns `MIN AGE` and `MAX AGE`.

I am trying to return four separate values:

```
If MIN AGE = 0 and MAX Age <> 0, return "MAX AGE"
If MIN AGE <> 0 and MAX Age = 0, return "MIN Age"
If MIN Age <> 0 And MAX AGE <> 0, return "BOTH"
If MIN Age = 0 and Max Age = 0, return "Correct as is"
```

Would I need to use tables for part of this?

Any assistance is appreciated!

Comment: You can use nested `IIf()` or a `Switch()` call.

Comment: You trying to do this in a query or VBA function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use *IIf*:

```
=IIf([MIN AGE] And [MAX AGE],"BOTH",IIf([MIN AGE],"MIN AGE",IIf([MAX AGE],"MAX AGE","Correct as is")))
```